# npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: vue.js, windows, npm, framework

Anteriormente tenia instalado @Vue pero como no es compatible con Vuetify desintale para instalar la version old 2, pero al tratar de instalar me sale este error en la consola:

```
PS C:\Users\Heyder> npm install vue
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Heyder\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Heyder\package.json'
npm WARN @vue/compiler-sfc@3.0.5 requires a peer of vue@3.0.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN Heyder No description
npm WARN Heyder No repository field.
npm WARN Heyder No README data
npm WARN Heyder No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ vue@2.6.12
updated 1 package and audited 2274 packages in 71.637s

62 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar instalándolo globalmente, según lo que muestras estás intentando instalarlo localmente sin haber inicializado un archivo `package.json`.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear un `package.json` mediante `npm init` (opcional: `-y` para saltarte las preguntas de inciialización) y luego instalarlo con `npm install vue`
2. Instalar globalmente el vue-cli `npm install -g @vue/cli` y luego inicializar tu proyecto con `vue create <nombre-de-tu-proyecto>`

Personalmente te recomiendo la segunda opción ya que el vue cli es bastante útil durante el desarrollo.